# In VS code jupyter manim magic command stops autocomplete and hint

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, manim

I want to use jupyter in VS Code to write manim code. However, if I put the cell magic command `%%manim -v WARNING --disable_caching Scene_Name` at the top of the cell, the autocomplete and parameter hint will be lost in the cell.

I wonder how to include the magic and retain the autocomplete + hint?

Snapshot: without %%manim, autocomplete and hints work properly
[image: without %%manim]

Snapshot: with %%manim, no hint pops out, autocomplete stops
[image: with %%manim]

Comment: Have you found the solution to your problem? I'm facing the same :<

Comment: @USHKA Luckily I have. Simply use line magic (not cell magic) `%manim ...` at the **end** of the cell containing the `class`, or any cell after evaluating the `class` that puts it in notebook memory.